# How to change the alignment of elements from flex-box in media queries?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm working on a project where I'm using bootstrap flex-box. I have attached the link to the layout that I'm using. I need to change the column on the right side to downwards when using on different devices except on pc.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/c6ttqiV.png]

This is **what I want to get** 
[image: RESULTANT IMAGE]

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="flex-column"></div>
    <div class="flex-column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do u want the box one by one?.. except pc

Comment: can you add a screenshot of how you want to display it on other devices. and please add full HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Do you want the first right div on bottom ???

Comment: what exactly you want?, can you mention that screen with code please

Comment: @nazifarashid, I want the second flex-column div to be at the bottom

Comment: @XenioGracias, I'm sorry I cannot add the whole code, there are around 1000 + lines of code and its in JSX. But I can provide you with an image of How I want to it to look like

Comment: you want to add one more row of three columns right?

Comment: please look at this image and tell me if you want to make structure like this or what?
https://prnt.sc/p3losb

Comment: The numbers of boxes on your images do not match. The first has seven boxes and the second has only six.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this... the right-most column gets to the bottom on a size smaller than `lg`... you can change the behavior on smaller screens through relevant classes;

**UPDATE**: added code for the same effect with flex

check the **code snippet** below:

```css
.leftSection div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.leftSection div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 300px
}

.rightSection div {
  border: 2px dotted pink;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.flexDirection>div {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flexDirection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
  .flexDirection {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.flexDirection>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.flexDirection>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flexDirection div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.leftSectionFlex>div:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.leftSectionFlexBottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row!important;
}

.leftSectionFlexBottom>div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.rightSectionFlex>div {
  border: 2px dotted pink;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<h2>Flex</h2>

<div class="d-flex flexDirection">
  <div class=" flex-column">
    <div class="leftSectionFlex flex-row">
      <div class=""></div>
      <div class="leftSectionFlexBottom">
        <div class=""></div>
        <div class=""></div>
        <div class=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" rightSectionFlex flex-column">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>
<!--
        -->
<h2> Bootstrap grid</h2>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="row leftSection">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="row rightSection">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need flex-box, not the css grid layout

Comment: @Maester_Sherlock, updated answer with flex options as requested

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap-4 you can follow this structure. bootstrap 4 grid structure is all depends on flex and you can use the following structure for the devices except PC for the structure you want.

```css
.box-content{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.big-box{
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-9">
      <div class="box-content big-box"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="box-content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="box-content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="box-content"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="box-content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="box-content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="box-content"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create it purely using `flex-box` in following way. But I would recommend you to go for `css grid` for 2 dimensional layout.

**Code:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  margin: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  flex: 4;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1;
}

.abc {
  display: flex;
}

.abc div {
  flex: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    display: flex;
  }

  .sidebar div {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div>1</div>

      <div class="abc">
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS Grid example:

https://gridbyexample.com

http://cssgrid.io/

Answer (score -1):

Same as You want.

```css
.demo{
        background: #000;
        height: 200px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <body>
<div class="container-fluid">    
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="demo"></div>
</div>    
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<div class="demo"></div>
</div>     
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<div class="demo"></div>
</div>     
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<div class="demo"></div>
</div>     
</div>
</div>    
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="demo"></div>
</div>    
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="demo"></div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="demo"></div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>    
</div>    
</div>
</body>
```